# Will Synology still recognize its drive after it's been assembled via mdadm on another OS?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm, synology, synology-diskstation

I have one HDD with a single Basic ext4 volume, and accidentally deleted some of my files on it. I want to try `extundelete` or `ext4magic` under Ubuntu, but I'm worried - does *mdadm assembly* modify the drive or its filesystem in any way, or just helps in accessing the data on the existing raid volume? I used `mdadm -A -R` a couple of times before for data recovery, but never tried to put those drives back into Synology after that (since they were dying in previous cases).

So the question is - can I take the HDD out of Synology, connect it to a Ubuntu PC, do `mdadm -A -R`, do some recovery on unmounted/readonly device, then `mdadm -S` after I'm done, and put the HDD back to work as if nothing changed?

Answer (score 0):

As your Synology box is built on Linux - ie using the Linux kernel - and since software raid is typically built into the kernel , it is extremely likely that this wont cause problems for your synology  but I doubt anyone here will give you a guarantee.  In any event this kind of block level opration comes with some risk so you should back up first.

I can state with a fair amount of certainty that mdadm does not modify the ststem in any way as it works at the block layer and is filesystem agnostic.

It does modify the drive by adding a superblock with the stuff mdadm needs to handle raid - and the location of this may vary depending on the version and if its a boot drive - but the commands you are proposing will not alter this.